# C/C++ How does the number of labels (goto) influence performance?

Tags: c++, c

I guess this mostly is about breaking the C/C++ optimizer.

```
l_line1:
   do_stuff(a, b);
l_line2:
   do_other_stuff(n, m, o);
l_line3:
   do_more_stuff(x);
```

Is there a difference for the performance if the labels are inside an `if` block if this is never true in a run?

```
if (debug_active) {
   l_line1:
   nextline = debugme(d1, d2, d3);
   goto nextline_check;
}
do_stuff(a, b);

if (debug_active) {
   l_line2:
   nextline = debugme(d1, d2, d3);
   goto nextline_check;
}
do_other_stuff(n, m, o);

if (debug_active) {
   l_line3:
   nextline = debugme(d1, d2, d3);
   goto nextline_check;
}
do_more_stuff(x);
return;

nextline_check:
   switch (nextline) {
     case 1: goto l_line1;
     case 2: goto l_line2;
     case 3: goto l_line3;
     default: DEB_ASSERT("Wrong line");
   }
```

**Background**:
These lines are inserted for a source level debugger.
The reason to have all these `goto` in is because the code is generated (both the "original" code - **translated from another language to C/C++** - which is the first sample without labels and the second one which is more or less what the debugging option generates).
If you want to be able to skip lines during debugging or even change the next statement (both would be set by the "user" during the function `debugme`) you need labels before every statement and `goto` these labels in dependence of the return (in this case simplified to the return code).

General ideas to get a better performance with a portable code will be nice, too (non-portable suggestions would be nice to know, too - at least for GCC and MSC).

Comment: Please tell me why are you using `goto`?

Comment: Good God, that code is basically "Goto considered harmful" made *manifest*.

Comment: @NicolBolas what do you mean? He says he is generating this code. Plus, no offence, but I think this "Goto considered harmful" stuff is harmful ;)

Comment: Very few of the "standard rules" of programming, including avoiding goto statements, apply to generated code.  They apply to the _code generator_ itself, yes.

Comment: @Ed Heal: Do you see *any* other option to allow a source level debugger (which is called by `debugme`) to set the next instruction?

Comment: 1. Write the code so that it is readable. *goto* does not lead to readable code as you have code that jumps around. 2. Debugging - Plenty of good debuggers let you step through the code etc. 3. Performance - Measure it first and find out where the performance problems are. 3. The optimiser is a lot better than you doing optimisation

Comment: @SimonSobisch - actually there are several ways to do it without labels and gotos - but they're so horrible you don't want to go there.  Just one example:  number each original source statement sequentially, generate each original source statement surrounded by `if (pc == nnn) { ... }` where `nnn` is the number of the statement, and `pc` is the "program counter" ... enclose all of that in a `while (1) {...}` and set `pc` appropriately at the top of the loop ... voilà, no labels.  But you don't want to go there.  You're on the right track.

Comment: @EdHeal - This code *is* for a debugger which should be able "to step though the code etc."!

Comment: @EdHeal - please focus on the question: the OP is talking about generated code. It does not have to be readable at all.

Comment: BTW, @SimonSobisch, GCC offers (or used to offer) an extension called "first class labels" that was useful for code for virtual machines, interpreters and the like.  A google search doesn't turn up any references in GCC documentation - perhaps it is called something else? or is no longer supported? - but here are two articles that reference it: [1](https://books.google.com/books?id=yfQn5cA---0C&lpg=PA184&ots=J1WRM9YCBv&dq=gcc%20%22first%20class%22%20labels&pg=PA184#v=onepage&q=gcc%20%22first%20class%22%20labels&f=false), [2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gnu.gcc.help/ScQmE0uPMws)

Comment: Ahh, found it: they call it [labels as values](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html).  It lets you implement a computed goto.  There are contexts where this can be better than the switch statement.  Still destroys optimization, but can be used to simplify generated code in certain ways that might still show performance improvements over your two variants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by "never true in a run" you're conceding that the variable `debug_active` can take values true or false at runtime - though only one such value in any given run - in other words, that it isn't a compile-time macro.  With that in mind:

It isn't the labels in-or-out of the if statement that will ruin the optimizer's ability to optimize this code.  It is the fact that the flow of control it depends on is completely destroyed in the second version by the call to `debugme` returning an int which is then used in a `switch` at `nextline_check` to dynamically choose the next block of code to be executed.  Any and every optimization that depends on data flow being computed by knowing the control flow will be defeated there.

The first version is better, but not much, as the labels will also confound many/all optimizations when the control flow can't be determined, as is likely in many cases.  Unless there's a `debugme`/`nextline_check` hiding somewhere that you haven't shown - in which case the same problem surfaces as in the second version.

(Actually for an apples-to-apples comparison we'd need to see the dispatch code in the first case, just like you provided it in the second case.)

In any event the "performance" of this generated code is going to suck badly no matter what you do (compared to the optimized not-instrumented original source).  Your only question is:  Will it suck badly enough to torpedo your debugger concept by frustrating users more than the benefits your debugger provides pleases them?

(P.S. just as a single simple example of what the optimizer will not be able to do in your second version:  It can't assume that any particular value is in a given register at the start of a statement (i.e., a statement that originally appeared in the source code) as a result of it having been left there in the previous statement.)

Answer (score 3):

Labels and `goto` in C and C++ are much like labels and branches in assembler, and that's probably what will be generated by the compiler. Do look at the generated code of your example program to see what the compiler does. If that's how labels and `goto` is handled, then the "performance" is like using the same in assembler.

It should also be noted that the compiler will generate a *lot* of jumps in the machine code, loops and conditions and function calls all cause jumps, and there's not much of a performance penalty for that. However, the compiler knows the details of the underlying CPU better than you do, and so can generate better jumps that doesn't trash the instruction cache or stall the instruction pipeline as much as your unconditional jumps will do, so using jumps might indeed cause a small performance hit, though it will seldom be noticeable unless you use labels and `goto` instead of loops or conditional statements.

That said, it's the *jump* that causes any possible performance problems, the labels themselves are just placeholders in the compiler so it can generate the correct jump offsets for the machine code. Once your program has passed the compiler the labels are no longer in the object file or the generated code.

And lastly the usual advice against using `goto`. While it might make sense in a *few* situations, most programmers will never come to a situation where `goto` makes sense. Simply don't use it, there are more often than not other constructs of the language that will be better suited, or at least more optimal and at the very least more maintainable.

Comment: This is the question to the answer: "They don't have any performance influence after compilation." Thank you. Nonetheless: How do you think the `goto` in this specific example (a source level debugger allowing you to set the next instruction) can be removed?

Comment: These statements are correct for assembly language programming (and therefore the resulting machine code) but _not_ in the context of running (generated) C code through a optimizing C compiler (or C++).  In _that_ case the _labels_ can make a performance difference because they are potential places a program can jump to, therefore they affect control flow _just by existing_ even if the jump to them never occurs at runtime (as long as a jump to them occurs in the source code such that the goto can't be proved by the optimizer to be dead code).

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the number of labels have any actual performance impact since there is no cost if nothing jumps to them - they are just possible (symbolic) destinations and result in no code in themselves and don't even make it to the final object file. Even if something jumps to them they are easily replaced by constants at the jump site. But you should easily be able to verify or disprove that by inspecting the generated asm - you should see all labels just vanish.

Comment: The context is labels in code processed by an optimizing compiler.  Labels do have performance impact in this case.

Comment: I worked on an optimizer for about 1 year.  The first thing it did was break the code up into "basic blocks".  A basic block starts with a label and ends with a jump, and has neither inside the block.  It would end up with a graph of basic blocks.  If it saw certain shapes of graphs it would just give up.  Adding labels and gotos was the only way to cause odd shaped graphs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it.  No goto required.

```
if (! debug_active) {
    // fast path when not debugging
    do_stuff(a, b);
    do_other_stuff(n, m, o);
    do_more_stuff(x);
} else {
   nextline = debugme(d1, d2, d3);
   while ( true ) {
      if( nextline == 1 ) {
          do_stuff(a, b);
          nextline = debugme(d1, d2, d3);
          if( nextline < 2 ) continue;
      }

     if( nextline == 2 ) {
        do_other_stuff(n, m, o);
        nextline = debugme(d1, d2, d3);
        if( nextline < 3 ) continue;
     }
     if( nextline == 3 ) {
         do_more_stuff(x);
         nextline = debugme(d1, d2, d3);
         if( nextline < 4 ) continue;
     }
     break;
   } // while
} // if

return;
```

Comment: This is "the only possible option without goto" davidbak pointed out in the comments - as this is generated it would be a possible option but would you do the same if you have not only 3 but 12000 nextlines? BTW: the idea of duplicate code for `!debug_active` is a good one!

Comment: Ah, davidbak's comment does match.  With 12,000 statements a switch (without breaks) would be better.  Let the compiler make the jump table for you.  Duplicating the code is a time-space trade off.